# Converting C code to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, mips

This is part of a program I have been working on and having trouble writing this lookup function part of the code. Here is the code in C but am having trouble converting it to MIPS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Pseudo codes:
  $a0 = 0       # index into symTab array
compare:
  if ($a0 >= symAV($0))
     goto not_found
  if (TOKEN[0] <> symTab[$a0])
     goto nextSym
 if (TOKEN[1] <> symTab+4[$a0])
     goto nextSym
  return        # found the symbol
nextSym:
 $t0++      # should be incremented by 16 in MIPS
 goto compare

not_found:
 $a0 = -1
 return
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? What have you done so far?

Comment: are you looking for a C compiler for MIPS?

Comment: I am new to MIPS programming and still dont know what all the registers etc mean. I just dont know how to come through line by line and write it in MIPS.

Comment: @ellio20: The whole idea of the MIPS architecture is reliance on a compiler. There's no point in manually writing MIPS assembler other than for writing the lowest level of an OS or in academic education.

Comment: What the symAV function doing? And why it's always passed $zr?

Comment: Modern compilers almost always produce better / faster machine code than hand-written assembly

Answer (score 3):

Get yourself a compiler capable of generating MIPS output, such as `gcc` and then compile your code with the option "produce assembly output". `gcc -S`  can do this for you.

Then take that code and examine/use it. If you want to *understand* it, you may want to ensure that optimisation is at a low level (such as with `-O0`). Otherwise there's a good chance you won't be able to make any sense of what the compiler generates.